# Pi 2 CPU Documentation

Tags: arm, cpu, assembly

I'm interested in processor architecture, and assembly programming, but I can't seem to find any documentation, or even the datasheet on the CPU of the Pi 2 (BCM2836). The  document I'm looking for should describe all the registers, instructions, architecture/pipelines etc of the CPU

Comment: The [instruction set is **ARMv7-A**](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0406c/index.html).  Looks like you have to be an "ARM customer" to get the manual though. >_<

Comment: Registration is free, but still a nuisance :\

Answer (score 2):

I'm not surprised you couldn't find any information.

The BCM2836 is a SoC not a CPU.  As far as you are concerned the BCM2836 is identical to the BCM2835 except for the different ARM CPU.

The main user CPU used on the Pi 2 is an ARM Cortex A7 with four cores.

If you search for BCM2835 and the ARM CPU you'll find all the information you could need.

Comment: Aah, I saw that very briefly one time, and wondered about it. When I worked with ICs at school, I always look up the datasheets by the exact number, just 'cause there's usually some minute variations between different chips. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The GPIO between Pi and Pi2 are not on the same addres.
This [link](http://www.valvers.com/open-software/raspberry-pi/step01-bare-metal-programming-in-cpt1/) will be help you.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.